# How can I access the attributes of an element by using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I access the attributes of an element by using JS? I tried (example) `element.style.width`. I only need the numeric value, I mean 50 instead 50px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

element.offsetWidth will give you the width as a numeric value.

Alternatively you could use element.style.width and parse it into a number with

```
Number.parseInt("50px")
```

or the faster bitwise version

```
~~("50px".replace("px", ""))
```

Comment: I used Shanon's answer. For my code was the best  solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.getComputedStyle(element).width`

Answer (score 0):

In this way...

```js
let theD = document.getElementById('theDiv');
theD.innerHTML = theD.offsetWidth;
```

```css
#theDiv {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div id="theDiv"></div>
```